# Блоки с фиксированной шириной, резиновые и контент в центре

Tags: css

Пытаюсь сделать следующее: два блока фиксированной ширины. Третий - резиновый и занимает всю остальную ширину. Внутри него три блока с содержимым, которое также занимает всю ширину этого блока, а содержимое внутри - выравнено в центре по вертикали и по горизонтали.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не очень выходит. Что не так?

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

#container {
  width: 750px;
  height: 500px;
}

#first,
#second,
#third,
#third-one,
#third-two,
#third-three {
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#first,
#second {
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
}

#second:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#third {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='first'>first</div>
  <div id='second'>second</div>
  <div id='third'>
    <div id='third-one'>third-one</div>
    <div id='third-two'>third-two</div>
    <div id='third-three'>third-three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: посмотрите flex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div {
 border: 1px solid gray;
}

#container {
 width: 750px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#first,
#second,
#third,
#third-one,
#third-two,
#third-three {
 min-height: 100px;
 margin: 10px;
}


#third-one,
#third-two,
#third-three {
 position: relative;
}


#third-one > span,
#third-two > span,
#third-three > span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#first,
#second {
 width: 250px;
 float: left;
 height: 500px;
}

#second:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}

#third {
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="first">first</div>
 <div id="second">second</div>
 <div id="third">
  <div id="third-one"><span>third-one</span></div>
  <div id="third-two"><span>third-two</span></div>
  <div id="third-three"><span>third-three</span></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @n.osennij обновил, добавил выравнивание